# MS SQL Server 2012 Error on TLog Backup

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2012

**I have a MS SQL Server 2012 installation on which I am restoring a SQL 2005 .bak which includes some full-text catalogues**

The original .bak has no conflicts with 2012 (as the migrate advisor was used to clear all of these). Upon running a TLog backup I receive the following error message:

`Executing the query "BACKUP DATABASE [databaseName] TO  DISK = N'..." failed with the following error: "An error occurred while processing 'BackupMetadata' metadata for database id 5 file id 1. Inconsistent metadata has been encountered. The only possible backup operation is a tail-log backup using the WITH CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR or NO_TRUNCATE option. BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.`

After much searching I am at a loss as to why. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you run an initial full backup yet?

Comment: Full backup is failing for a similar reason. We have reason to believe it's something to do with the fulltext catalogues and so we're currently trying to remove them prior to backup on 2005 and recreating them on 2012 after the restore.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out we needed to remove the full text catalogs from 2005 then take the backup. We then recreated the catalogs in 2012 and all is good. Following a single full backup, the t-log maintenance plan runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

YOu have a problem in the database - this is not a backup error, the reason is that backup - as it says - found bad data in the database.

Use DBCC to find what is wrong with the database. Then open a nwew question with the issues it finds.